# Solution by radicals of $(1+x)^n=x^m$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the equation $$(1+x)^n=x^m$$ where $m$ and $n$ are two different natural numbers, I was trying to find as many solution as possible expressing them without transcendent functions.

WLOG we can suppose $n<m$ and coprime, in this case by the Abel–Ruffini theorem we know we can find a closed form solution for $m<4$. So I found solutions for $(n,m) \in \{(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(3,4)\}$

Indeed, by playing with the numbers, I noticed that also $(1+x)^4=x^5$ has closed form solutions as the equation is divisible by $x^2+x+1$.

How can I find other solutions *violating* Abel-Ruffini?

Comment: what you mean by violating Abel-Ruffini?

Comment: A remark: The polynomial $P(x)=(1+x)^n-x^m$ is divisible by $x²+x+1$ if $n$ is even and $3$ divide $2n-m$.  Simply show that $P(j)=0$ using $1+j=-j^2$ with $j=\exp(2i\pi/3)$.

Comment: @Masacroso it was just a joke: I just meant peculiar cases still solvable with $m>4$.

Answer (score 1):

The difference of powers formula can yield solutions for $m>4$:
$0 = (1+x)^{n} - x^{m} = (1+x)^{n} - (x^\frac{m}{n})^{n} = (1+x-x^\frac{m}{n})((1+x)^{n-1}
+(1+x)^{n-2}x^{\frac{m}{n}} + \ldots + (x^{\frac{m}{n}})^{n-1})$.

Under the assumption that $m>n$, then the zeros $1+x-x^{\frac{m}{n}}$ will yield all possible solutions.  The huge benefit here is that zeros of this polynomial can be quickly found using [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).  This can help you find your desired *other* solutions.

Comment: I am trying to understand, so the equation $\left(1+x\right)^5-x^4$ has a solution for $x=-0.461$. When I construct this equation: $1+x-x^{\frac{5}{4}}$ I get a root of x=3.08. What is it I did wrong. I would like to ask you to provide an example. Thanks.

Comment: @NoChance, my approach only works in the instances where the power of $x^{m}$ is higher than the power of $(1+x)^{n}$.  Otherwise, it will only capture 1 of potentially 2 solutions.  In your case, you want to solve roots of $1+x-x^{\frac{4}{5}}$.

Comment: OK, I tested with $(1+x)^4 - x^5$ with $1+x+x^{4/5}$ and it worked. Root is about 3.08 - Very nice. I will test more....Here is the link: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dzcmy0y3as